# Rotating rectangle not pointing towards player accurately

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a game where a rectangle rotates toward the player but it does not point accurately. I'm pretty sure that i don't have good math skills. Thanks!

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '30px Arial';
 
var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;
var timeWhenGameStarted = Date.now();   //return time in ms
 
var frameCount = 0;
 
var p = {
 x:50,
 y:50,
 spdX:30,
 spdY:5,
 w:20,
 h:20,
 aimAngle:0,
 //
 pressingDown:false,
 pressingUp:false,
 pressingLeft:false,
 pressingRight:false,
};

var e = {
 x:100,
 y:100,
 spdX:30,
 spdY:5,
 w:20,
 h:20,
 aimAngle:0,
 //
 pressingDown:false,
 pressingUp:false,
 pressingLeft:false,
 pressingRight:false,
};

function lineToAngle(ctx, x1, y1, length, angle) {

    angle *= Math.PI / 180;

    var x2 = x1 + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);

    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

    return {x: x2, y: y2};
};

function aim(){
 // var y = p.y-10;
 // var x = p.x-10;
 // var angle = Math.atan2(y, x)-0;
 
 var diffX = p.x - e.x;
 var diffY = p.y - e.y;
 
 e.aimAngle = Math.atan2(diffY,diffX) / Math.PI * 180
 
 ctx.beginPath();
    lineToAngle(ctx, 200, 200, 40, e.aimAngle);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();
};
 
function udp(){
 if(p.pressingRight)
  p.x += 10;
 if(p.pressingLeft)
  p.x -= 10;
 if(p.pressingDown)
  p.y += 10;
 if(p.pressingUp)
  p.y -= 10;
   
 if(p.x < p.width/2)
  p.x = p.width/2;
 if(p.x > WIDTH-p.width/2)
  p.x = WIDTH - p.width/2;
 if(p.y < p.height/2)
  p.y = p.height/2;
 if(p.y > HEIGHT - p.height/2)
  p.y = HEIGHT - p.height/2;
};

function getkeys(){
 document.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68)        //d
   p.pressingRight = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
   p.pressingDown = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   p.pressingLeft = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   p.pressingUp = true;
 };
  
 document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68)        //d
   p.pressingRight = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
   p.pressingDown = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   p.pressingLeft = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   p.pressingUp = false;
 };
};

function update(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 
 aim();
 
 ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
 ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
 // ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 // ctx.fillRect(e.x, e.y, e.w, e.h);
 getkeys()
 udp();
};

setInterval(update, 20);
```

```html
<h4>Click on the canvas & then use WASD keys as controls</h4>
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas></center>
```

Comment: is the green square always supposed to be visible?

Comment: Do you mean inside the canvas?

Comment: yes of course, after you start

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to stay visible

Comment: sometimes it disappears

Comment: When does it disappear?

Comment: a lot!!! if you hold down a key or actually the first time i clicked on the canvas and pressed W it disappeared

Comment: you should set a max-count on the number of times you can keydown on a key at in succession

Comment: It seems like your logic is correct... just need to adjust the range of numbers you're calculating in...Do what @Spencer says... seems ok.

Comment: @RachelGallen What browser are you looking at the snippet from? I'm not having any disappearing issues in Chrome.

Comment: i am when i run the snippet in full page in chrome

Comment: @RachelGallen Strange, I'm viewing the snippet in full-screen with that same Chrome version and cannot get anything to disappear.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek. I belive Rachael Gallen means the rectangle is allowed to move off canvas (the OP must add some collision detection in a future version).

Comment: i can post a screenshot

Comment: @markE That's possible, but I would not consider that a disappearing problem. As it's merely something the OP didn't add to the program, I've seen several programs in which the user did not add side boundaries.

Comment: @RED sorry for editing your q but i'm just elaborating

Comment: @RachelGallen It's what **@MarkE** mentioned, the user did not add side boundaries for the block, so it can move off the screen. That being said it's not really disappearing. For example, you can press W, then press S, and the block will move back down.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i'm just pointing it out as a problem for the OP. sometimes if you hold down a key it takes quite a while for it to reappear

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes but's it's extra functionality, and it's not entirely important for the problem that the user is having. It's not a problem with the example, it's simply something the user did not add and not a bug in the program. While it's rare, some people do leave off boundaries on purpose.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek he said explicitly that it's always supposed to be visible. Read the comments. Its a bug

Comment: @RachelGallen The OP probably thought you meant that you stated the block disappears from the screen in-view. It's not disappearing and reappearing, it's simply moving in a position off of the canvas. I can tell the OP how to add that functionality to it, but it would be noise to the real problem at-hand. It's like stating that the block not moving with the arrow keys is a bug. Or that the Canvas not re-sizing with the screen is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple your mismatch in the position of the black line. As you have for `e` the position `100,100` but being drawn on position `200,200`. You simply need to change the position for `p` to match what is being placed here:

```
 lineToAngle(ctx, 200, 200, 40, e.aimAngle);
```

So change it to `100,100` (what's in the `e` object), or change it to:

```
lineToAngle(ctx, e.x, e.y, 40, e.aimAngle);
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = '30px Arial';
 
var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;
var timeWhenGameStarted = Date.now();   //return time in ms
 
var frameCount = 0;
 
var p = {
 x:50,
 y:50,
 spdX:30,
 spdY:5,
 w:20,
 h:20,
 aimAngle:0,
 //
 pressingDown:false,
 pressingUp:false,
 pressingLeft:false,
 pressingRight:false,
};

var e = {
 x:200,
 y:200,
 spdX:30,
 spdY:5,
 w:20,
 h:20,
 aimAngle:0,
 //
 pressingDown:false,
 pressingUp:false,
 pressingLeft:false,
 pressingRight:false,
};

function lineToAngle(ctx, x1, y1, length, angle) {

    angle *= Math.PI / 180;

    var x2 = x1 + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y1 + length * Math.sin(angle);

    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

    return {x: x2, y: y2};
};

function aim(){
 // var y = p.y-10;
 // var x = p.x-10;
 // var angle = Math.atan2(y, x)-0;
 
 var diffX = p.x - e.x;
 var diffY = p.y - e.y;
 
 e.aimAngle = Math.atan2(diffY,diffX) / Math.PI * 180
 
 ctx.beginPath();
    lineToAngle(ctx, e.x, e.y, 40, e.aimAngle);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.stroke();
};
 
function udp(){
 if(p.pressingRight)
  p.x += 10;
 if(p.pressingLeft)
  p.x -= 10;
 if(p.pressingDown)
  p.y += 10;
 if(p.pressingUp)
  p.y -= 10;
   
 if(p.x < p.width/2)
  p.x = p.width/2;
 if(p.x > WIDTH-p.width/2)
  p.x = WIDTH - p.width/2;
 if(p.y < p.height/2)
  p.y = p.height/2;
 if(p.y > HEIGHT - p.height/2)
  p.y = HEIGHT - p.height/2;
};

function getkeys(){
 document.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68)        //d
   p.pressingRight = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
   p.pressingDown = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   p.pressingLeft = true;
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   p.pressingUp = true;
 };
  
 document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 68)        //d
   p.pressingRight = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 83)   //s
   p.pressingDown = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
   p.pressingLeft = false;
  else if(event.keyCode === 87) // w
   p.pressingUp = false;
 };
};

function update(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 
 aim();
 
 ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
 ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
 // ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 // ctx.fillRect(e.x, e.y, e.w, e.h);
 getkeys()
 udp();
};

setInterval(update, 20);
```

```html
<h4>Click on the canvas & then use WASD keys as controls</h4>
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas></center>
```

Comment: still the disappearing issue

Comment: @Red No problem, you can accept this answer with the check mark on the left. Glad to help, your math was correct, just a simple positioning problem :).

Comment: 44.0.2403.157 chrome disappearing issue - click on the canvas and click W

Comment: run the snippet in full page mode

Comment: should add the unsimplified formula as a comment somewhere. `e.aimAngle = ((Math.atan2(diffY, diffX) * 360) / ( 2 * Math.PI)) * (2 * Math.PI / 360); ` .. also, modifying `e.aimAngle` (i.e. `angle *=` ) in a helper function seems improper to me. the formula for getting the angle only needs dx, dy, or x1 x2 y1 y2..